# Ubuntu compatible with HP Envy 17

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, hp

Brand new to Ubuntu.  Just bought a HP Envy 17.3" Touch Screen Laptop, Intel i7, 12GB RAM, 512 GB SSD.  17M-CE0013DX.  A techy friend is recommending Ubuntu over Windows for security, stability, and privacy. Is this laptop compatible with Ubuntu?  I did not see it on a a site listing Ubuntu certified hardware. If so which version of Ubuntu is recommended. Thanks.

Comment: Create a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and try and boot to it. That'll give some clue.

Comment: I suggest that you try a live session of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from a DVD or USB and see for yourself. My only concern is the Airplane Mode switch. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: +1. I don't understand the downvotes on new ubuntu users. At least downvoters should leave a comment explaining what is wrong, so in the future the users don't feel afraid of participating in this community.

Comment: Thanks for responses and links.  I did try to look for my question before asking but I am not that familiar with this site.  I am surmising this won't be as clean as I had hoped.  I am going to use a USB after I gather more information.

Comment: @tom z Most manufacturers, even HP, do not commit to the expense of getting consumer laptops certified for Ubuntu, or any other Linux. If you have a problem testing with the LiveUSB of 18.04, come back here to let us know (in detail, please) what you did and what happened which you did not expect. After you have tried Ubuntu 18.04, you can try other flavours, too. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows many times with no problems, but if you have a problem, we're here. Just keep it bite-sized; small chunks of questions, please.